# Changing links on homepage - SEO

Tags: seo, links, dynamic

I have a website whose ranking is constantly fluctuating on Google.  On a search for my site name I could be the ranked 1st at one moment, then 20th or so a matter of hours later!

I have been tearing my hair out trying to figure it out as I am sure the site is well optimized.

I am starting to believe that it may be the fact that I have a homepage which is unlikely to be the same on repeat visits.  I display advertisements in three sections, and the homepage displays four small ads from each of these three sections, chosen at random on each page load, with links to further information on the ad.  As such repeat visits to the page by Googlebot would display different content, and have links to different pages.

Would this be a factor in my ever changing ranking?  If so is there are way to change this while maintaining my current method of random ads on the homepage?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance

J

Comment: Fluctuations like this are normal. Stop micromanaging your site SEO like this. Focus on content and what your users want/need.

Comment: John is exactly right! Fluctuations are normal especially lately with all of the updates that Google has been doing. It seems like semi-radical fluctuations are at least normal for now. As well, measuring the performance of the home page is just plain wrong headed. The home page often does not rank for anything in particular very well and is not a good indication of anything at all. Your home page is important, however, it is not content which is what you should be measuring.